# Returning const char*; how ugly is static?

Tags: c++, python, c, swig

For reasons beyond my control, I need to return `const char*` from a function, but I don't know what the `char`s need to be at compile time.  My solution is something like the following:

```
const char* __str__() {
  static std::string String;
  String = [some fancy stuff];
  return String.c_str();
}
```

The `static` prevents the string's destruction on exiting the function, but it also means that the memory sticks around until my program exits (right?).  Because the returned string can occasionally be *huge* (GBs), this can be a real problem.

I usually avoid pointers at all costs and only ever use `static` for class members, so I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing.  Is this guaranteed to work?  Is there a better way?

[The context of this question is printing a complicated object in python, using the `__str__` method.  I define the method in my c++ code, which is then wrapped by SWIG.  The SWIG example shows the use of `static`, but it's not clear to me that that's the only way.  I am open to suggestions.]

Comment: There must be a way to do this without a `static std::string`. Could you link to the SWIG example?

Comment: The SWIG example is [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn43).  It uses `static char[]`, of course, but `std::string` is just the result of my `fancy stuff`.

Comment: AFAIK, SWIG handles the `std::string` return type automatically and turns into a string in the target language. If it's not doing this, you can always go edit your interface file to insert the conversion code, but this will involve messing with whatever C API Python provides.

Comment: @Prætorian: That's the correct answer.  I can just return a `std::string`, rather than `char *`.  I was misled by the SWIG documentation's example.  Good call.  Now somebody should really turn that into an answer...

Comment: There has got to be a way to rename the function in SWIG so it doesn't have to be called `__str__` in C++.

Comment: @Omnifarious, `%rename(targetname) orgname;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Prætorian said, SWIG can return std::string to Python.  Here's an example from the SWIG example I think you are looking at.  Also shown is a way to avoid using a reserved name in C++:

#### x.i

```
%module x

%{
#include "x.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%rename(__str__) display;
%include "x.h"
```

#### x.h

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class Vector
{
public:
    double x,y,z;
    Vector(double a,double b,double c):x(a),y(b),z(c) {}
    ~Vector() {}
#ifdef SWIG
    %extend {
        std::string display()
        {
            std::ostringstream temp;
            temp << '[' << $self->x << ',' << $self->y << ',' << $self->z << ']';
            return temp.str();
        }
    }
#endif
};
```

#### Output

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import x
>>> v = x.Vector(1.0,2.5,3.0)
>>> print v
[1,2.5,3]
```

Answer (score 10):

`static` presents additional troubles besides the allocation scope:

- The function is not reentrant
- There is no way to clean up when the caller is done with the return value

Any reason not to return the value and let the caller free it?:

```
const char* __str__() {
    char *s = malloc(2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);  // 2 GB
    [some fancy stuff with s];
    return s;
}

...

const char *magic = __str__();
[do something with magic]
free (magic);  magic = NULL;   // all done
```

Comment: Well, I could, but I'd have to do it in python, which would break my ability to do things like `print(MyCrazyObject)`.  I know there exist better ways to do this, but I want one that just uses friendly, familiar python.

Answer (score 3):

This is guaranteed to work, with significant caveats.

All of the caveats boil down to two basic issues that combine in a way that's not very pleasant:

1. There is only one instance of `String` in your **entire** program.
2. `String` is not a constant.

This will cause you all kinds of interesting issues. For example, if you call `__str__` again somewhere else in your program, anybody who's saved a copy of the `const char *` you handed back to them may end up holding an invalid pointer. And even if they aren't, they will end up hold a pointer to memory that has changed. In short, the result will be undefined behavior.

Another example, if you call `__str__` from more than one thread, it will blow up at some point as both threads try to simultaneously modify `String`.

Fortunately, you don't have a static initialization order problem. `String` is guaranteed to be initialized the first time you call `__str__`.

You can solve the problem of `String` staying around forever by calling `String.clear()` in `__str__` if you're sure that nobody has any `const char *`s around pointing into the state of your `String`. `String.clear()` will free up any storage it might be using.

Personally, I'd only use this as a technique of last resort. The possibility of random parts of the program having squirreled away a pointer would worry me endlessly. There is no clear indicator of the lifetime of this pointer, aside from the fact that it cannot be guaranteed to work if `__str__` is ever called again. But then again, it might, depending upon exactly what `__str__` does.

Also, `__str__` is a bad name to be using. Names containing two consecutive underscores are reserved for the C++ implementation.

Comment: Good point about the threads.  But if I clear `String` in the function, on return, the `const char *` will be invalid.  Also, regarding the name `__str__`, it's not my name; it's python's.

Comment: Names containing two consecutive underscores anywhere are reserved, not just at the beginning.

Comment: @bames53: Interesting. I didn't know that. Would you happen to know where in the standard I should look for that?

Comment: [global.names] 17.6.4.3.2 "Each name that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use."

Comment: @bames53: Thanks! What an interesting rule. `__fred` is perfectly legal by that rule. :-/

Comment: No, that contains a double underscore. The uppercase letter is only for names that begin with an underscore.